# What does a "Team Flare Bag" do in Super Training?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

It says - "For some reason knocking the stuffing out of this bag feels so good" in the description. Considering its rarity I dont want to waste it if it is any good, so anyone has any idea what this thing is for?

Update - I did some save scumming, and upon using the bag I got a message saying - "Your Haxorus is bursting with Energy". And nothing of notice happened.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Team Flare bag increases the "punching" speed of your Pokémon, just as if you woke them up after a rest, but they will stay in this state far longer than if they simply rested. This means that they will use up punching bags faster and will find other punching bags at a higher rate when punching the default bag.

Comment: Actually, it reduces the amount of strikes required to break another bag by half.